# Get rating metadata form a list of song (MP3) in android using android.media.Rating

Tags: android, file, metadata, mp3, rating

I need to retrieve the rating from a list of all the songs in a phone.
Currently I have them on a File List. Some metadata can be listed with MediaMetadataRetriever but the ratings saved in the song by BlackPlayer EX can't, so I need to extract them with another method.
I've found "android.media.Rating" but with no luck.

My code so far:

```
String musicPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Music";
textView.setText(musicPath);
File directory = new File(musicPath);
textView.setText("On it");
MP3FileFilter fileFilter = new MP3FileFilter();
List songsFiles = listFiles(directory, fileFilter, true);
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
for(int i = 0; i<songsFiles.size(); i++){
    String song = songsFiles.get(i).toString();
    mmr.setDataSource(song);
    ((Rating) songsFiles.get(i)).getStarRating();
}
textView.setText("Done");
```

The error displaying is pretty obvious but I can't find a way to solve it:

```
java.io.File cannot be cast to android.media.Rating
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with JAudioTagger jar and this code:

```
MP3File musicFile = (MP3File) AudioFileIO.read((File) songsFiles.get(i));
    if (musicFile != null && musicFile.hasID3v2Tag()) {
        ID3v23Frame frame = (ID3v23Frame) 
        musicFile.getID3v2Tag().getFrame(ID3v24Frames.FRAME_ID_POPULARIMETER);
        FrameBodyPOPM body = (FrameBodyPOPM) frame.getBody();
        Long irating = body.getRating();
}
```